# SQL Standard Username (root) and Password (blank) not working

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to create a 'register' page for a site I'm working on - a significant jump for me. I'm hosting the page on Biz.nf, and I have created a database on 'phpmyadmin', and found the code to connect the register page to the mysql.(As follows.)
(Comments in brackets have been replaced.)

```
<?php
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "(my database)";
$server = "(my server)";
mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
?>
```

But when I load the webpage, I get the error message:

**Warning:** mysql_connect(): Connection refused in /srv/disk11/(biz.nf id)/www/(my website).co.nf/register.php on line 9

This is confusing. It *found* the server, it just didn't accept the username/password. Which is strange, because this is apparently the mysql default. To the best my knowledge, I haven't altered this default in any way, so I don't know what that would trip it up.

Any help? Sorry if this is obvious, but this is a big step up in coding for me.

Comment: It looks to me as though you are configuring it to use a network port...  Do you have the mysql server configured to accept network connections??  It's indicating that the connection was refused (no port) rather than an authentication failure.

Comment: Are you sure the root password is really blank? Or that you can use root at all and not a special account configured for you?

Comment: this host stuff is in your host dashboard or control panel. We can speculate it is `localhost` or whatever. None of that matters but their support pages. He is one in [This Link](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-setup-biznf-to-work-with-wordpress). I am sure you can look up something current

Comment: read this http://ccm.net/faq/673-phpmyadmin-access-denied-for-user-root-localhost

Answer (score 0):

Try this, mysql in php is deprecated:

```
 <?php
 $host = "(my host)";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $database = "(my database)";
 $db = mysqli_connect($host, $user_name, $password, $database);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "(my database)";
mysql_connect($host, $server, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($db);
?>
```